Store ordered array on memory/Register - ARM
I'm new in ARM development and I need to figure out a lot of things but i need to complete this task.
Just to summarize the problem, I have a non ordered array : ( values are a representation of <Day, value>, so pos 0 and pos 1 come "together" )
Failed_runs     DCD     0x02, 50, 0x05, 30, 0x06, 100, 0x01, 58
                DCD     0x03, 40, 0x04, 90, 0x07, 25 

I need an ordered version of it based on the value in desc order and store the day in a second array of value.
The expected value is something like :
Failed_runs_ordered     DCD 0x06,0x04,0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x07

I made this code and implemented a bubble sort to have the sorted array but I cannot see if my data have been ordered correctly. I tired to store it in a register, as the code shows, but when I loop it I obtain strange value like memory segmentation fault or memory empty.
code :
                AREA    |.text|, CODE, READONLY , ALIGN=2 
               
                ; BOUNDARY 
                SPACE 4096          
Days            DCB     0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 

                
                SPACE 4096
Best_times      DCD     0x06, 1300, 0x03, 1700, 0x02, 1200, 0x04, 1900
                DCD     0x05, 1110, 0x01, 1670, 0x07, 1000 

                
                SPACE 4096
Failed_runs     DCD     0x02, 50, 0x05, 30, 0x06, 100, 0x01, 58
                DCD     0x03, 40, 0x04, 90, 0x07, 25 
                 
                        
Best_times_ordered      SPACE   32
                                       
Failed_runs_ordered    SPACE   32 
                           
                SPACE 4096      
Num_days        DCB     0x07 


; Reset Handler

Reset_Handler   PROC
                EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK]                                            
                
            LDR R1, =Best_times
            LDR R0, =Failed_runs      ; Punto di partenza dell'array Failed_runs
            LDR R6, =Failed_runs_ordered
            LDRB R2, Num_days         ; Carica il numero di giorni (7)

outer_loop
            MOV R8, #0                ; Inizializza l'indice interno
            MOV R11, #0 
inner_loop
            LDR R3, [R0, R8, LSL #2]  ; R3 = giorno corrente
            ADD R8, R8, #1           ; Avanza di 2 per passare al prossimo elemento
            LDR R4, [R0, R8, LSL #2]  ; R4 = valore corrente
            SUB R8, R8, #1            ; Torna indietro (ripristina R8)

            ADD R9, R8, #2            ; Calcola l'indice per il prossimo giorno
            LDR R5, [R0, R9, LSL #2]  ; R5 = giorno successivo
            ADD R9, R9, #1            ; Avanza R9 per caricare il prossimo valore
            LDR R7, [R0, R9, LSL #2]  ; R6 = valore successivo
            SUB R9, R9, #1            ; Torna indietro

            CMP R4, R6
            BGE no_swap               ; Se R4 >= R6, non fare lo swap

swap_elements
            STR R5, [R0, R8, LSL #2]  ; Scrivi giorno successivo nella posizione corrente
            ADD R8, R8, #1            ; Avanza per scrivere il valore
            STR R7, [R0, R8, LSL #2]  ; Scrivi valore successivo
            SUB R8, R8, #1            ; Torna indietro
            STR R3, [R0, R9, LSL #2]  ; Scrivi giorno corrente nella posizione successiva
            ADD R9, R9, #1            ; Avanza per scrivere il valore
            STR R4, [R0, R9, LSL #2]  ; Scrivi valore corrente
            SUB R9, R9, #1            ; Torna indietro

no_swap     
            STR R3, [R7, R8, LSL #2] 
            ADD R11,R11,#1; Scrivi giorno corrente in Failed_runs_ordered
            STR R5, [R7, R8, LSL #2] 
            
            ADD R8, R8, #2            ; Passa alla prossima coppia
            CMP R8, #12
            BLT inner_loop            ; Continua fino a completare la passata

            SUBS R2, R2, #1
            BNE outer_loop            ; Continua fino a quando tutto è ordinato

    
            MOV R8, #0
            
check       LDR R3, [R7, R8, LSL #2]  ; R3 = giorno corrente
            ADD R8, R8, #1
            CMP R8, #12
            BLT check   

I'm missing how to store the variable correctly or there are any other type of error? Thanks and if something necessary is missing, let me know and I will add.

CMP R4, R6 is very suspicious due to LDR R6, =Failed_runs_ordered. Learn to use a debugger to single step the code.

This question on .equ maybe helpful.  Ie, you can use .equ Rcount R8  or some meaningful name for values that you don't intend to be scratch.  You can use all UPPER case for register or prefix with 'R'.  Keeping track of registers is difficult.  It maybe in the comments, but those are not accessible to everyone.
